# Elegant pandas way to stratified frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if I can reach my desired result with a "better" way? This means with less steps (but readable code!) and some pandas in-build features.

That is the input data

```
>>> df
  name sex group
0    A   w     x
1    B   m     y
2    C   m     y
3    D   w     y
4    E   w     y
5    F   w     y
6    G   m     y
7    H   w     x
```

That is the desired output

```
      x    y
sex
 m    0    3
 w    2    3
```

##### My current solution

```
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton3
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': list('ABCDEFGH'),  # 8 persons
        'sex': list('wmmwwwmw'),
        'group': list('xyyyyyyx')
    }
)

r = df[['group', 'sex']].value_counts().reset_index(name='n')
#   group sex  n
# 0     y   m  3
# 1     y   w  3
# 2     x   w  2

r.pivot(columns='group', index='sex')
```

The result is that:

```
         n
group    x    y
sex
m      NaN  3.0
w      2.0  3.0
```

At the end it is fine. But I thought that I can solve this with less steps and maybe with a tweak to `pivot()` or something else.

Comment: See [**`pandas.crosstab`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html).

Comment: Can you give an example fitting to my MWE please. I tried some things but didn't work out. e.g. `pd.crosstab(df.sex, columns='group')`

Comment: Pass first two arguments as columns of data frame.

Answer (score 4):

You want a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(df['sex'], df['group'])
```

output:

```
group  x  y
sex        
m      0  3
w      2  3
```